# cron expression for time complexities

Tags: cron, expression

What would be the cron expression to run every 4 days starting from November 7th, 18:35 PM 2015 to December 25th, 11:30 AM 2019.

Can someone shed a light on this complex cron expression, all the examples i see on the net was not combining the interval days and start date/time to end time/date.

regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
35 18 */4 0
```

That will get you what you want.  I would use a date checking conditional in the script to keep it in the range you've decided.

Something like:

```
if [$(date +%Y%m%d) -ge 20151107] && [$(date +%Y%m%d) -le 20151225]
```

Obviously I'm being hasty in the conditional...if you wanted to include time (11:30 pm) you'd want to either add more logic or play with the date format to make sure you were getting what you need.  Also, I'm assuming that the script that you're cronning is a shell script.  If it's not then my syntax for the conditional is not accurate.

You could also use other cron expressions to start and finish the job...
November 7th, 18:35 PM 2015 to December 25th, 11:30 AM 2019.

```
#1
35 18 7 11 * 2015 chmod +x /path/to/script

#2 - base
35 18 */4 0 test -x /path/to/script && /path/to/script

#3
30 11 25 12 * 2019 chmod -x /path/to/script
```

Comment: but where did we mentioned the dates and the months and the end time, i see only the start time and the every 4 days interval.

Comment: Yeah, you could just do an append, like if [$today -ge $start] && [$today -le $finish]

Comment: can you give me the cron expression for the above usecase

Comment: I did.  As I said, the date range handling would be best within the script scheduled by cron.  The best you can do in cron is specify time and every fourth day.

Comment: I understand what you said when you reply it, but in our use case, we cannot do that, i am trying to create a cron expression for the above scenario and invoke the quartz scheduler in java, so we cannot create a cron expr by including all the dates and times and intervals??

Comment: Why call the Quartz scheduler directly from cron?  You could also use a script to pass a SOAP envelope from cron (assuming it's a Web service or BPEL) or a script to call Quartz.

Comment: you meant to say we cannot put the entire scenario in one cron expression, is it really that hard to represent in cron expr...

Comment: Not in a single cron expression.  Everything will be a workaround to the base cron expression.  You can also cron two separate jobs to enable and disable the base cron expression based on date.  If you're invoking Quartz directly through cron this may be the way you want to go.

Comment: I just edited to add a trifecta of crons if you want to invoke Quartz directly